# Can not find Ajenti after installation

Tags: nginx, configuration

I just installed Ajenti to my server, that runs nginx. I have a domain already setted up and everything works, except Ajenti.

I added this config to nginx, to reach Ajenti:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name ajenti.XY.dk;

        access_log /XY/_log/ajenti.access.log;
        error_log /XY/_log/ajenti.error.log;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
        location /* {
                rewrite /* http://127.0.0.1:8000 permanent;
        }
}
```

And yes, I added a symlink to sites-enabled for it. But I can not reach it from outside.
I tried Linx on the server and it opened Ajenti, so it is running.

What should I change in my config?

Answer (score 0):

Use `proxy_pass` instead of rewrite.